# How to unarchive MLMultiArray with NSKeyedUnarchiver?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsobject, coreml, nscoding

I want to store `MLMultiArray` data predicted from CoreML into local file, because `Core Data` does not support for this type, I tried out `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, as `MLMultiArray` conforms to `NSObject`.

However, this Object can be `encode` & save successfully but can not be `decode` correctly.

```bash
error is: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "value for key 'embedding' was of unexpected class 'MLMultiArray' (0x1e35d84b8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreML.framework].
Allowed classes are:
 {(
    "'CoreMLApp.Embedding' (0x1002a53f8) [/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C86A850C-27F6-43CB-82AF-9223/CoreMLApp.app]",
    "'NSArray' (0x1e3380b50) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=value for key 'embedding' was of unexpected class 'MLMultiArray' (0x1e35d84b8)
```

Below is my Object:

```swift
class Embedding: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true
  
    var id: String?
    var embedding: MLMultiArray?
    
    init(id: String, embedding: MLMultiArray) {
        self.id = id
        self.embedding = embedding
    }
    
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.id, forKey: "id")
        aCoder.encode(self.embedding, forKey: "embedding")
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? String
        self.embedding = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "embedding") as? MLMultiArray
    }
}
```

The encode/decode part:

```swift
    private func saveEmbeddingsData(embeddings: [Embedding], fileName: String) -> Bool {
        let filePath = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: embeddings, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            try data.write(to: filePath)
            return true
        } catch {
            print("error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return false
    }

    private func loadEmbeddingsData(fileName: String) -> [Embedding]? {
        let filePath = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: filePath)
            let embeddings = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClasses: [Embedding.self], from: data) as? [Embedding]
            return embeddings
        } catch {
            print("error is: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    private func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let arrayPaths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return arrayPaths[0]
    }
```

I've tried with `NSCoding` rather than `NSSecureCoding`, but all `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveXXX` methods output errors that require the data to conform `NSSecureCoding`.

Comment: Try adding `MLMultiArray.self` to the classes array parameter in the call to `unarchivedArrayOfObjects`.

Comment: @HangarRash thanks your comment. My object is a Class which contains `id:String` and `embedding: MLMultiArray`, so you can see I use `try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClasses: [Embedding.self], from: data) as? [Embedding]` in the `loadEmbeddingsData` function. Is that what you want me to try?

Comment: Try changing the `ofClasses: [Embedding.self],` part to `ofClasses: [Embedding.self, MLMultiArray.self],`

Comment: @HangarRash Wow! you're a genius.  I'm curious how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSSecureCoding and NSKeyedUnarchiver require that you specify the types of classes you are expecting. The whole idea is to avoid someone sneaking in unexpected, crafty values that could compromise the security of your code.

Since you archive an array of `Embedding`, the archive also contains values of type `MLMultiArray`. This means that when you unarchive the data you must specify that you expect values of type, `NSArray`, `Embedding`, and `MLMultiArray`.

Since you are using `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects` you don't need to explicitly specify `NSArray`. But you do need to pass `[Embedding.self, MLMultiArray.self]` to the `classes` parameter.

The error message is the big hint.

```
Allowed classes are:
 {(
    "'CoreMLApp.Embedding' (0x1002a53f8) [/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C86A850C-27F6-43CB-82AF-9223/CoreMLApp.app]",
    "'NSArray' (0x1e3380b50) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=value for key 'embedding' was of unexpected class 'MLMultiArray' (0x1e35d84b8)
```

This is telling you that only `Embedding` and `NSArray` are allowed since that is all you told `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects` to expect. And the error tells you that it found `MLMultiArray` in the archive but it was not in the list of allowed classes.

This is resolved by changing the line:

```
let embeddings = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClasses: [Embedding.self], from: data) as? [Embedding]
```

to:

```
let embeddings = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClasses: [Embedding.self, MLMultiArray.self], from: data) as? [Embedding]
```

To me, the biggest issue with NSSecureCoding is that it breaks encapsulation. Your code to unarchive needs to know the internal details of the `Embedding` class. One solution to this may be to add helper methods to the `Embedding` class to do the archiving and unarchiving so other code doesn't need to know what classes need to be specified.

Comment: Your explanation was both clear and straightforward, super thanks!

Comment: I agree with you on the point that "NSSecureCoding breaks encapsulation". A swift newbie like me, find the solution was using a stange method, not elegant at least.